# EF6 eager load single property of related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

IN EF6, i have an entity Customer, with a navigation property to entity Address. Address entity contains a property "City".

I can eager load the Address entity while getting all Customers like this:

```
_dbSet.Customers.Include(customer => customer.Address);
```

This gives me all the customers, with all the Address properties eager loaded.

Of course this works fine, but the only thing i need from the Address table is the field "City", and it does not feel good to fetch all the address properties from the persistent data store (SQL Server) while not needing them.

I tried the following:

```
_dbSet.Customers.Include(customer => customer.Address.City);
```

...but this gives me a runtime exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'MyModel.Address'does not declare a navigation property with the name 'City'.
```

I understand this, since City is just a field, and not a relation to another table / entity.

But is there another way to accomplish what i want, or is it best practice to just include the whole Address entity, even if i only need the city field???

What i want is that i can use myCustomer.Address.City, without having an extra query to the database, but for examle when i use myCustomer.Address.Street, the Street property is not eager loaded, and should be additionally fetched from the database...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are *really* set on using the same entity throughout your code base, then you could get around the issue using something similar to what Stef proposed:

```
var query = _dbSet.Customers.Include(customer => customer.Address);
var data = query
    .Select(c => new { Customer = c, City = c.Address.City })
    .ToList() //executes the IQueryable, and fetches the Customer and City (only) from the DB
    .ForEach(x => x.Customer.Address = new Address { City = x.City })
    .Select(x => x.Customer)
    .ToList();
```

I am very much in favour of DTOs and *not* using entity objects in the whole code base, but the above will give you a list of `Customer`s which have `Address` objects with only the `City` field populated. Obviously, I make the assumption that your objects have public setters, which entity objects typically do have.

Comment: Thank you for your "workround", but more thanks for your recommendation about using custom DTO's instead of the entity objects. I think for now i will use the entity objects in my code base, but when there is need for extention, like in the above case,i will create a custom DTO.

Answer (score 5):

Select only the properties you want, EF will only load what's needed.

```
var query = _dbSet.Customers.Include(customer => customer.Address);
var data = query.Select(c => new { Customer = c, City = c.Address.City });
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I already considered this as an option, but i did not want to use anonymous types. For examle when i put your code in a method in my data access later, and i want to return a collection of those objects (return the var data from your answer), what should be the return type of this method?

Comment: Use projection as suggested by Stef is a good solution. If you don't want to deal with anonymous types you can create a CustomerSmallInfoDTO that will contain only properties you just need.

Comment: @SlimH2S, correct that's a good design. And when you use AutoMapper, you can easily map entities to DTO objects.

Comment: You should also map Customer to an proxy/DTO, and not use the entity throughout your application.

Comment: `.Include(customer => customer.Address)` is not needed. `_dbSet.Customers.Select(c => new { Customer = c, City = c.Address.City })` will do.