# EF: Eagerly include single field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have in my database an `Object` which has an object `Owner`. `Owner` has a string `Name`. `Object` also holds object `Details`.

I need the `Object`, it's `Details`, and the `Owner.Name`. I want to prevent loading the whole `Owner` object (as detailled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282032/ef6-eager-load-single-property-of-related-entity)) and I want only a single database query.

I tried:

```
DataContext.Objects.Select(o => new { Object = o, OwnerName= o.Owner.Name })
           .Include(o => o.Object.Details);
```

but it throws:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The result type of the query is neither an EntityType nor a CollectionType with an entity element type. An Include path can only be specified for a query with one of these result types.

Also tried calling `Include` before `Select`:

```
var d = DataContext.Objects.Include(o => o.Details)
.Select(o => new { Object = o, OwnerName= o.Owner.Name });
```

But this ignores the `Include`, ie. Accessing `d.Details` causes a DB query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're touching on an issue that does exist in EF.

The problem lies in how EF handles the loading of data. It loads *all scalar properties* of an object, but not the navigational properties.

`Include` influences this behavior, by telling EF to *also* include a specified navigational property (with all of its scalar properties)

But then we get to `Select`. When you use this, you are essentially giving a **fixed** list of columns that you want to retrieve. This overrides the default behavior of loading all scalar properties, which sadly also overrides the `Include` statements that you added.

---

The simplest solution is to explicitly tell EF to retrieve the details:

```
var d = DataContext.Objects.Include(o => o.Details)
    .Select(o => new { 
               Object = o, 
               ObjectDetails = o.Details,
               OwnerName= o.Owner.Name 
    });
```

As an aside, since the `Select` explicitly states which columns EF needs to retrieve, you don't need the `Include` statement anymore.

This behavior can already be seen by you retrieving `o.Owner.Name` without actually calling `Include(o => o.Owner)`.

Comment: Works as wanted when accessing ``Details`` via `d.ObjectDetails`, but reading `d.Object.Details` will cause another DB query.

Comment: @JackMiller: You could shuffle your data around: `foreach(var entry in d) { entry.Object.Details = entry.ObjectDetails; }`. A little bit of extra work, but not that expensive since it's an in-memory reference assignment.

Comment: Will EF notice that it is actually the same object? I am afraid that this shifting might cause unnecessary update operations or even that ``context.SaveChanges()` might fail with some exception.

Comment: @JackMiller: This should be fine, as far as I'm aware. EF simply avoids loading the navprop because you could have e.g. only wanted to load the _enabled_ details (i.e. a subset), which would cause issues if that was automatically loaded as the nav prop (as in some cases it can cause the deletion of the details that were not loaded, when you commit changes). It should definitely work after closing your context; if that's relevant for you.

Answer (score 0):

This *should* do it (though `Details` are loaded in a separate property to correct for @Flatter's comment):

```
DataContext.Objects
           .Include(o => o.Owner>)
           .Include(o => o.Details)
           .Select(o => new {Object = o, 
                             OwnerName = o.Owner.Name,
                             Details = o.Details});
```

It returns a new `object` with `Object` set to the selected `Object` (consider renaming this if you can, its very confusing), and an `OwnerName` populated from the Owner table without loading the entire Owner.  It also populates `Details` as a separate property, since `Select` ignores the `Include`.

I say it "should" work, because without seeing your table structure, I have to guess based on your descriptions of how things are connected.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. `Select` effectively undoes `Include` because it specifies a custom column retrieval (which overrides the default load behavior which in influences by Include)